# Is it possible to host my RoR website on my university's servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, passenger

I understand that the best way to deploy a rails site is with passenger. But I'm not really sure what that means. Do I buy a web hotel? Do set up my own server if my needs aren't that big?

I've got access to an area on my schools servers where we are encouraged to set up a website. We gain access to the area by using a VPN client to connect to "sslvpn.ntnu.no" and then connecting to "smb://webedit.ntnu.no/username" on my mac.

The info says that everything we pute there is available publicly on http://folk.ntnu.no/username.

Is it possible for me to deploy rails here? Can I use passenger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout http://herokuapp.com its free for basic usage, its a great place to play with rails for free. And you can always scale it to a large production site if you need.

The elongated answer is probably not, passanger needs to be specifically configured with apache or nginx, its unlikely your university has done this and has configured it for student sites. Do you have SSH access to your schools server, if not it would be very difficult to deploy as well. I'm going to guess most signs point to no.

Also using SMB or Samba, indicates it may be a windows box, also not a good sign.

Comment: Thats where I'm deploying right now, during development. But when the site launches it should be able to handle 1-2k visits a day. Im not really sure how that translates to dollars on heroku. Their pricing talkes about web dynos and worker dynos which doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: You could always try using an EC2 micro instance, running nginx and passanger, we pay around 20-30$ a month for a micro. Should easily handle 1-2k visitors a day. I would assume you'd be fine using heroku for that volume as well, but the answer your question is, no rails will not work on your UNIV hosting.